# StackExchange.Redis Send Structs

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am new to redis and I wonder how to send a `class` or a `struct` with [StackExchange.Redis](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/).

So lets assume I want to write

```
    var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
    var db = redis.GetDatabase();
    db.StringSet(key, value);
```

This is actually only possible if my value is primitive. So is there any other way to achieve sending complex types without serializing them as json?

Comment: We utilised this package to do this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CachingFramework.Redis/ - to save us any extra work of handling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Redis is not aware of your `class` or `struct`, you'll need to define how to store it. A recommended way is to store the object as a hash, where the key is the property name, and the value is the property value. Note that this does not support object graphs, e.g. nested collections or complex types.

As per the [documentation on data types](https://redis.io/topics/data-types):

> A hash with a few fields (where few means up to one hundred or so) is stored in a way that takes very little space, so you can store millions of objects in a small Redis instance.

Alternatively, you could serialize the object yourself and store it as a `string/byte[]`. Json is one format, which includes the property names in the data, which is great for versioning. E.g. if a new property is added, you wouldn't need to go and change all existing data. The downside is that it takes up a lot of space. You could use any other form of serialization as well, e.g. [binary serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization).